# How to create a custom chained filter method with new Function

Tags: javascript, string, function, methods

#### Situation

I've got a table and for each column, the user can set multiple filters, like:

`ID is greater then 10 && lower then 40 && is equal to 22`

#### Data

I pass the applied filters with the correct operator and the checking value, like this:

```js
const filters = [
  {
    value: 10,
    operator: '<'
  },
  {
    value: 40,
    operator: '>'
  },
  {
    value: 22,
    operator: '=='
  },
]
```

One column data could look like this:

```js
const columnData = [10,22,3,1,14,15,69,22,...]
```

#### Draft

I want to minimize the filtering and compare the data values with all applied filters only once.
Since I don't know what the user is looking for, I want to create a custom chained filter method.

With the `new Function`-method I thought it will be a perfect use case for a chained filter string, like:

`colData < 10 && colData > 40 && colData == 22`

#### Goal

```js
const colVal = 22
const testFn = new Function('colData',
'return colData > 10 && colData < 40 && colData == 22' // <- should be a custom string
)
console.log(testFn(colVal)) // true;
```

Now I'm stuck to create a custom string that's represents my filters.

I thought, I could create the string in the first place, use it in the `testFn`-method and compare each value smoothly.

I tried the following:

```js
const colVal = 22
const y = (colData) => `${colData}` + ' > 10 && ' + `${colData}` + ' < 40 && ' + `${colData}` + ' == 22'
const testFn = new Function('y', 'colVal',
'return y(colVal)'
)
console.log(testFn(y, colVal )); // 22 > 10 && 22 < 40 && 22 == 22
```

Do have a idea to implement a custom string into a `new Function` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your conditional filter string based on the filters array using `map` and `join` methods, then pass that string to the main function body string to the `Function` constructor.

```js
const filters = [{
    value: 10,
    operator: '>'
  },
  {
    value: 40,
    operator: '<'
  },
  {
    value: 22,
    operator: '=='
  },
]

const columnData = [10, 22, 3, 1, 14, 15, 69, 22]

const filterString = filters.map(({ value, operator }, i) => `el ${operator} ${value}`).join(' && ')
const fnString = `return data.filter(el => ${filterString})`
const fn = new Function('data', 'filters', fnString)

console.log(fnString)
console.log(fn(columnData, filters))
```

Comment: Thanks, looks the way I wanted it! Let me stick my head around what I was missing.